# Is there a way that I can hide the page URL without hiding the page number while printing?

Tags: css, url, printing, hide

I'm trying to hide  the page URL while showing the page number

I found some possible solutions on other questions, but none of them helped me.

```
@media print {
    a:after { content:''; }
    a[href]:after { content: none !important; }
}
```

The code above was supposed to hide the page URL, i guess.

Comment: Have you tried this one: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-hide-links-using-css-3466933

Comment: I took a look at this link and tried to use something from there, but no success. I even tried to inspect the URL on Chrome and set some CSS property on it, but nothing.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can set the URL background color to the same of the page, this way hiding it while printing?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to print options and you can hide from there, like Firefox.

> Print -> Page Setup -> Margin & Header/Footer -> Headers & Footers. Set it to '--blank--'.

Is not possible in Chrome and with css because is not a part of the html page.
And that code remove the urls only from the html page.